# react render don't show anything

Tags: reactjs, npm

I created this navbar component in react

```
import './nav.css';
import react from 'react'

export default function NavBar() {
  return (

    // bootstrap navbar component
<div className = "NavDiv ml-auto"> 
<div className = "topPortion "  >
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Get the app</a>
    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse ms-auto justify-content-end " id="navbarNav">
      <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto ">
       
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link active " href="#">
          Add Restaurant
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link active" href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link active">SignUp</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
<img className= "zomatoPic" src = "https://b.zmtcdn.com/web_assets/8313a97515fcb0447d2d77c276532a511583262271.png" alt= "zomato name pic" />
<h2 className="zomatoPic2"> Discover the best food & drinks in chennai </h2>
</div>
 );
}
```

and imported it in the app.js

```
import react from "react";
const NavBar = import('./NavBar')



function App() {
    


    return <NavBar />

    


    
}

export default App
```

and then I imported this to the main index.js and tried to render using ReactDOM.render like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = import('./components/App')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

but not getting any output and only a blank screen.

this is the locaiton of the files
[image: the image shows the location of the files]

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- bootstrap stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <div id="root"></div>
  
  
  
  
  </body>
  <!-- bootstrap script -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

and this is my nav.css folder that styles the navbar component

```
.NavDiv {

    width: 100%;
    height: 30rem;
    background-image: url("https://b.zmtcdn.com/web_assets/81f3ff974d82520780078ba1cfbd453a1583259680.png");
    background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}

.topPortion {

    padding : 0 200px 0 20px;
}


.zomato {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 5rem;
}
h1{
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.zomatoPic2{
    display: block;
width : 50rem;
    margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
img{
    display: block;

    justify-content: center;
    width: 20rem;
    margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
color: #fff;
}
```

I Don't know why it is not rendering anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `import()`, which is for dynamic imports and returns a promise.

You'll need the static import form

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

instead. The same stands for the import of `NavBar` in the app file.

Secondly, in the NavBar file, you need to import React as `React`, not `react`:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

Static import is useful when you required your component to mounted during complete application run time . Even different different route will open but static component will always present and will be mounted.

Dynamic import is useful where you want your component to unmount when you navigate to different route.

Dynamic import is supported in react using `lazy()` and `Suspence`.

Dynamic import should be bottom of static import otherwise you will get Error

```
import Snackbar from "./component/shared/Snackbar"
const Dashbaord = lazy(() => import("./screens/admin/Dashboard"))
const Profile = lazy(() => import("./screens/admin/Profile"))
```

Then you can use Suspense to mount dynamic component with fallback loading.

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <Suspence fallback={<p>Loading Screens...</p>}>
            {/* suppose you are working with react-router-dom v6 */}
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
                    <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashbaord />} />
                    <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Suspence >
    )
}
```

Fallback helps to show some placeholder when your component will loading and going to mount.